# remove <div> tag from html in JSoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I tried to scrape some content from a web site. I used `JSoup`. I tried what was,

```
List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Element s : doc.select("#core")) {
    System.out.println(s.html());
    songs.add(s.text());
}

for (String chord : songs) {
    System.out.println(chord);
}
```

`#core` is a `<pre>` tag. In this `<pre>` tag, I have a div like following,

```
Intro: <u>G</u> - <u>Em</u> - <u>C</u> - <u>D</u>
<u>G</u>
Would you dance,
<u>Em</u>
If I asked you to dance?
<u>C</u>
Would you run,
<u>D</u>
And never look back?
<u>G</u>
Would you cry,
<u>Em</u>
If you saw me crying?
<u>C</u>        <u>D</u>     <u>G</u>
Would you save my soul tonight?

<div id="part1">

    <div class="inner">
        <u>G</u>
        <u>D</u>
        <u>C</u> I can be your hero baby
        <u>G</u>
        <u>D</u>
        <u>C</u> I can kiss away the pain
        <u>G</u>
        <u>D</u>
        <u>C</u> I will stand by you forever
        <u>G</u>
        <u>D</u>
        <u>C</u> You can take my breath away
    </div>
 </div>
```

When I'm scrapping this, `Jsoup` isn't maintain the correct format in `div`. Is there a way to get the `<pre>` tag content as it is?

Comment: Can you explain what do you expect and what you get in more detail? I don't understand your problem at all so far.

Comment: I'm scrapping a content from a website. When I'm scraping it using Jsoup, It's not giving the original format(with spaces etc.) of the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just scrape the content without parsing it, then you can do something like this

```
Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("URL_HERE").execute();
System.out.println(response.body()); //This will keep the format as it is from the server.
```

If you want to parse the content after that, then do this

```
response.parse();
```

If you want to remove some element then you have to parse the content. But if you parse it, then any format that was there will be lost.

A workaround would be to escape the element that you want to keep the whitespaces. Check this from the author of Jsoup https://stackoverflow.com/a/5830454/1138559
Although you have to escape the contents of `<pre>` since it contains html elements too.